# Keep Excel Formula Static When Inserting Cells Into Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a spreadsheet that has prices, quantities, and extended prices for items.

|  Item  | Price  | Qty  |  Extended  |

|  A.... | 3.00. | 3.....|  9..............|

|  B.... | 2.00. | 3.....|  6..............|

|  C.... | 5.00. | 3.....|  15............|

|  D.... | 4.00. | 3.....|  12............|

Where the Extended column uses the formula (=b2*c2) on down.

The issue that I'm having is that this spreadsheet constantly gets new additions in the middle of it. For instance:

|  Item  | Price  | Qty  |  Extended  |

|  A.... | 3.00. | 3.....|  9..............|

|  B.... | 2.00. | 3.....|  6..............|

|  E.... | ........ | ...... | 15............ |

|  C.... | 5.00. | 3.....|  12............|

|  D.... | 4.00. | 3.....|  ................|

I selected the cells A4-C4 and inserted cells above those. The problem arises in the amount of information that I have on this spreadsheet. It has over 4000 rows currently. As you can see in the example, the formula of cell D4, which is displaying 15, changed with the insertion from (=b4*c4) to (=b5*c5)

To get the result that I want, I just copy the formula down from a box above it and gt it to show the correct value:

|  Item  | Price  | Qty  |  Extended  |

|  A.... | 3.00. | 3.....|  9..............|

|  B.... | 2.00. | 3.....|  6..............|

|  E.... | ........ | ...... | ............... |

|  C.... | 5.00. | 3.....|  15............|

|  D.... | 4.00. | 3.....|  12............|

Problem is, with 4000 rows to go through, the thing takes forever to get to the bottom and fully update.

I've tried every combination of using the $ in the formula to keep it constant, but to no avail. So finally, the Question:

Is there a way to make it so that when I insert cells into my chart, like I described, the reference still stays the same (=b4*c4) before and after inserting, without having to go through and recopy the formula every time?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, mis-read your post.

You can make the area of your data a table:

[Copying formula to the next row when inserting a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849629/copying-formula-to-the-next-row-when-inserting-a-new-row)

Comment: Sorry, mis-read your post. Making your data a table should work.

Comment: +1 for using a table. It makes all these problems go away. Formulas, formatting, etc will automatically be applied to new rows that are appended or inserted into a table. Click Insert -- Table to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just insert a complete new row.

Then enter in your data and drag the formula above down one

Comment: That works for the formula of it, but I also have a running total that gets off that way.